# Remove adjacent element in a list in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to do a simple python program that removes all the adjacent elements in a list

```
def main():
    a = [1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
    c = len(a)

    for i in range (0, c-2):
        if a[i] == a[i+1]:
            del a[i]
            c = len(a)

    print a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the output is

`[1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6]` which is all fine!

If change the a list to `a = [1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6]`

then it gives an error

index list out of range

```
**if a[i] == a[i+1]**
```

It shouldn't be complaining about the index out of range as I am calculating the len(a) every time it deletes an element in the list. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range (0, c-2):
```

This is not like a `for` loop in some other languages; it’s iterating over a list returned (once) by `range`. When you change `c` later, it does not affect this loop.

You *can* use `while` instead:

```
c = len(a)

while i < c - 2:
    if a[i] == a[i + 1]:
        del a[i]
        c = len(a)
    else:
        i += 1
```

There’s also [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

def remove_consecutive(l):
    return (k for k, v in itertools.groupby(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
origlist=[1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
newlist=[origlist[0]]
for elem in origlist[1:]:
  if (elem != newlist[-1]):
    newlist.append(elem)
```

The `itertools` answer above may be preferred, though, for brevity and clarity...